# OpenCLLink eating up all host memory

Tags: memory, opencllink

I am calling lots of OpenCL functions from Mathematica. The problem is that the memory the kernel uses grows and grows until the RAM is fully occupied.

I have created a small piece of code to demonstrate the behaviour.

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
openclPlatform = 1; openclDevice = 1;

For[i = 0, i < 1000, i++,
 OpenCLMersenneTwister[1, Platform -> openclPlatform, 
   Device -> openclDevice]; 
 ]
```

(OpenCLMersenneTwister is a predefined function by Mathematica)

When running that piece of code multiple times I can see that the RAM usage of MathKernel.exe grows and no memory is freed.

Is it a bug in Mathematica or is my code wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar bug in CUDALink. It appears to be related to memory management of MTensor objects passed back to *Mathematica* from the CUDALink or OpenCLLink library. The problem, as far as I can tell, arises due to the LibraryFunction defined in `` OpenCLLink`Private`cGetMemory["Double"] `` which specifies a shared return. This means that the library will keep ownership of the returned MTensor until it is explicitly disowned. Presumably there is a bug in the library code so that it never disowns the MTensor and the memory is never freed.

My workaround is to unload the `cGetMemory` function and then reload it, specifying automatic return instead of shared return. This should cause the library to lose ownership of the MTensor when it is returned to *Mathematica*, so the memory will be freed as soon as *Mathematica* has done with it.

Example:

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];

(* kernel memory grows by size of returned array on every call *)
Table[OpenCLMersenneTwister[100000]; MemoryInUse[], {5}] // Differences
(* {820520, 819352, 819352, 819352} *)

(* apply the fix *)
With[{func := OpenCLLink`Private`cGetMemory["Double"]},
  Module[{args = List @@ func},
   LibraryFunctionUnload[func];
   func = LibraryFunctionLoad @@ Delete[args, {4, 3}]]];

(* kernel memory is now under control *)
Table[OpenCLMersenneTwister[100000]; MemoryInUse[], {5}] // Differences
(* {16, 16, 16, 16} *)
```

If your GPU is single precision only you probably need to use "Single" instead of "Double". To similarly patch CUDALink just put `CUDALink` in place of `OpenCLLink`.

I can't be certain that there aren't any nasty side effects to this workaround, as I don't understand LibraryLink very well, but I have used this fix on CUDALink and been able to run code for >24 hours, transferring tens of gigabytes from the GPU back to host memory without the *Mathematica* kernel running out of memory.

Comment: This fixes the memory issue. Thank you very much! Without you we would have never found this fix.

Comment: Maybe it really has side effects. I now get "OpenCLFunction::outmem: OpenCLLink ran out of available memory, possibly due to not freeing memory using the memory manager.". But all memory is freed using OpenCLMemoryUnload

Comment: @user2224780, that's a shame, as I said it has been working for me with CUDALink. I'm not sure if that message refers to host or device memory - what does the mathkernel memory usage look like when you get that error?

Comment: MathKernel.exe looks normal and does not grow. It must be device memory...

Comment: @user2224780, if you're sure you are freeing all the memory you've allocated then either my fix is breaking something as you suggested, or there is another bug in OpenCLLink. Sorry I can't be more help! Maybe Wolfram technical support can help...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tested it and got  lot of errors

`Delete::partw: Part {4, 3} of {D:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\GPUTools\Libra
      ryResources\Windows-x86-64\OpenCLLink.dll, OpenCL_oGetMemory_Double, 
     {Integer, True | False}, {_, _}} does not exist.`